# How do I escape reserved words used as identifier in Netezza

Tags: netezza

One can use delimited identifier in JDBC query and it works with below databases even for a non reserved keyword with below delimiters:

SQLServer: Square bracket => [select]

Postgres, Teradata, Oracle, Sybase and DB2: double quote =>  "select"

For Netezza I tried single quote as per documentation, but it did not work. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_quoted_mixed_literals.html

Please suggest.

Comment: Show us what you tried, and show us the error you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works at my site is the " (double quotes) around table/column names  containing reserved words, spaces, special/national characters, numbers at the beginning and many other things a good data model does not contain (opinion - I know, but a heart felt one)
You need to be aware that anything referenced using "surrounding", becomes cAsE sensitive.

Try querying the catalog view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS using your favorite sql-client (aginity?) and look carefully at the caSiNg etc of the names of the columns/table you try to reference.

Hope this helps - otherwise please post a simple piece of sql that you would expect to succeed, along with the error message you got back, just as ScottMcG suggested

Comment: No problem - been there hundreds of times myself :)